# Pyspark Launch issue Windows 10 wxith Python 3.6

Tags: python, pyspark

I am unable to launch Pyspark in windows after installing Python 3.x with Anaconda.
Getting below error -

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pyspark
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\prudra\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 62, in <module>
    import pkgutil
  File "C:\Users\prudra\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pkgutil.py", line 22, in <module>
    ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'module_finder name ispkg')
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in namedtuple
    cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
```

Please let me know how to resolve

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019

Answer (score 0):

PySpark 2.1 currently does not work with Python 3.6.0. This issue has been reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019). It has been resolved on the 17th of January 2017, but has not been released as of today (17 March 2017). However, looking at the committed changes, you should be able to fix this yourself by downloading the following two Python files:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/serializers.py
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py

and saving them to the following location (overwriting the existing files):

C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark

or more generic the files should be saved to the `python\pyspark` subfolder of your Spark installation.

Comment: Thanks Jaco. How ever I am still getting below issue

Comment: 17/03/19 22:12:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\prudra\Desktop\Udemy\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.sessionState.

Comment: It seems other changes may have been made in Spark 2.1.1.You could try downloading the most recent nightly build: http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-branch-2.1-bin/spark-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-2017_03_18_02_58-780f606-bin/

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.1.1 just released on May 4th. It's now working with Python 3.6, you can see the release note [here](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-1-1.html).