# Error - pyspark with python via anaconda in windows 10/ 8.1 machine

Tags: pyspark

Pyspark is not recogonized in a windows 10 or 8 machine.

I read few stackoverflow post like [Pyspark install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861020/pyspark-launch-issue-windows-10-wxith-python-3-6), [Unable to run pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349980/unable-to-run-pyspark) but they said issue with spark version. But my question is Is there any other way to install pyspark in windows machine but not wasting too much time in fixing issues because i need for my project. Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest another way is to use Cloudera VM.

If you have a personal windows machine. Please download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install [cloudera vm](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-10.html) using that virtualbox.

Let say you have 16GB machine, so set 8 GB for that cloudera virtualbox. After booting the cloudera vm via virtualbox.

Open terminal and type pyspark.

[image]

Now you can install [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) as you can save your workspace for future reuse. As per your question this is the least time consuming method.